# MAMP, FreeTDS, ODBC, and ssh tunnel port forwarding almost working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, ssh

I am attempting to connect with php to a remote mssql server.  Since the mssql server is behind a firewall, I am using ssh tunnel with port forwarding to access it from my Macbook.

```
ssh -N -L 1433:<mssql_server_ip>:1433 username@www.example.com
```

The tunnel works fine as I am able to use Navicat to connect to the mssql server and I am able to telnet to it.  I have freetds and odbc installed correctly and running under MAMP locally.  It is only php that is unable to connect to the server.  Which leads me to believe that there is some small piece of my configuration that is causing it to fail.  I also am thinking that the tunnel and port forwarding may be an issue for freetds.

I tried various version numbers as well, as I read somewhere that this solved this problem for someone else, but hasn't helped me at all.

```
$ TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H 127.0.0.1 -p 1433
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

This is the php pdo connection I am trying to establish:

```
$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=127.0.0.1; Port=1433; Database=db_name; UID=user; PWD=password;');
```

Before I got freetds and odbc configured I was getting a unable to find driver error.  Now it appears to be able to try the connection but returns the message in the browser "No data received".  There are no errors in my php error log.  The page just fails to load in the browser.  I'm hoping someone out there has gotten this type of connection working and might have some insight into what might be going wrong.  I am happy to provide more details, just let me know what info would be helpful in debugging this.

Lastly and most frustrating, is that this works on the production server just fine and took only a couple minutes to get up and running from this [article](https://secure.kitserve.org.uk/content/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-php-ubuntu-using-pdo-odbc-and-freetds)...